# Electrical question

Tags: electrical

when placing one lead on the neutral side of the circuit and one lead on the hot side of the circuit we find proper voltage. However, when move one lead from the "hot" side of a switch to the opposite we find that we have lost power.  What does this tell us about the circuit?

Comment: That the switch is open.... This sounds like a homework question tho....

Comment: Actually, either the switch is closed or the switch isn't connected to anything.

Comment: @Tester101 maybe I'm misreading, but the way I read it one lead is connected to N (elsewhere in the circuit) and the other lead is testing first one side of the switch, then we move that lead to the other terminal of the switch.

Comment: @Tyson you're right, I misread the question.

Answer (score 2):

If a switch is *on*, there should be very close to zero volts across the switch.  That is to say, both sides of the switch will measure 120V when compared to neutral, and 0V when compared with each other.

If the switch is *off*, there should be 120V between the always-hot side and neutral... 0V between the downline side of the switch and neutral.  In between the sides of the switch, it will be indeterminate depending on what the load is.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what this tells us is that the fundamental charteristics of a circuit can easily change from parallel to series depending on where the measurements are taken.

On a ordinary off/on toggle switch, the switch opens and closes via a series circuitry.  There is no power consumption at the switch ( a smart switch w/ neutral would though because the black and white are connected in parallel!).

When looking at the different characteristics of parallel and series, they behave totally different.  Class dismissed!